# Issue with Firebase Image URLs in React Native Application

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am working on a React Native application with Firebase and Expo, and I am facing issues with image URLs.

I am using Firebase Storage to store my images, and I have implemented the image upload feature in my application. However, when I try to get the URL of an uploaded image, it returns a URL that points to an undefined image so in my application I don't have my image except its "skeleton"

I checked in firebase storage, and the URLs saved for my images are also undefined. I expect these URLs to point to the uploaded images.

Here is a snippet of the code where I am picking and trying to upload and get the image URL:

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

if (!image.canceled) {
      setImage(image.assets[0].uri);
    }

const addPost = async (data) => {
if (image) {
const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${Date.now()}`;
image, {
         contentType: 'image/jpeg',
       });
)
const response = await uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image);
const URLimage = await getDownloadURL(response.ref);
console.log("Image URL: ", URLimage);
// Here, URLimage is a URL, but it points to an undefined image
// Exemple of URL : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/yowl-join.appspot.com/o/images%2FBQxDprUiJ7VL4j1CuMWxWukLM742%2F1706977884063?alt=media&token=[token]

// Saving the URL in Firestore
await addDoc(collection(db, "posts"), {
  userID: auth.currentUser.uid,
  post: post,
  likes: "",
  imageUri: URLimage,
  username: getUsername(),
  timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
});

//...
```

In my app when I pick an image from my library then I show it on my app just before the POST , so I can see my image is correctly show so the problème it's after my POST.

[image: Image in my app]

Here is my firebase storage

[image: Firebase storage]

I can't get a preview of my image in firebase

I've tried to import a picture directly on firebase storage, and put the URL directly in my code and I have the entire image show in my application.

[image: My image put direclty in firebase storage]

I have thoroughly reviewed my code, checked Firebase Storage rules, and ensured proper authentication.
I think the problem come from the

```
const response = await uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image);
```

because the image file in my storage only weight 9 bytes. It contains "undefined"
I've tried with just a 'uploadBytyes' but I have : ReferenceError : Property 'uploadBytes' doesn't exist.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and have suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: Files of 9 bytes typically means that you didn't read the file's contents. Since there's no call to `pickImage`, we can't see how `image` gets populated. But set a breakpoint on the call to `uploadBytesResumable`, run in a debugger, and check `image` and you'll see it's not one of the types that the Firebase SDK expects.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I need to convert the URI of the image into a "blob" before send it to firebase

```js
const pickImage = async () => {
    let image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
// Some code 
if (image){
    const response = await fetch(image);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, blob);
```